# xltabular breaking booktabs

Tags: booktabs, xltabular

I want to have a page-filling and -breaking `longtable`, so I decided to try `xltabular`. Unfortunately `xltabular` seems to screw up the `booktabs` rules in the normal `tabular` environments, see:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, xltabular}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tabular}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \toprule
    col1 & col2 & col3 \\
    \midrule
    row 2: & more and moooooooooooore & test \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: xltabular breaking booktabs in normal tabular environment]

Not loading `xltabular` resolves the issue.

Did I miss some package option or some incompatibilities?
Is there a better package than `xltabular` which doesn't break `booktabs`?

(I am using TeXLive 2019 and compile with lualatex)

---

## EDIT (by Skillmon)

I reduced the bug to the following MWE (which doesn't make much sense on its own), it looks like `booktabs` tries to be smart detecting something, but fails badly.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\let\xltabular\relax
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \toprule
    col1 & col2 & col3 \\
    \midrule
    row 2: & more and moooooooooooore & test \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

It seems to suffice that `longtable` is loaded and `\xltabular` is defined (even if it's just `\relax`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*This bug is confirmed in `booktabs.sty` version 1.6180339 from 2019/10/08, I don't know whether it is present in earlier versions.*

I reported the bug to the maintainer of `booktabs`. In the meantime, it looks like it could suffice to do the following redefinition of `\@BTrule` in your preamble:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\makeatletter
\def\@BTrule[#1]{%
  \ifx\longtable\undefined
    \let\@BTswitch\@BTnormal
  \else\ifx\hline\LT@hline
    \nobreak
    \let\@BTswitch\@BLTrule
  \else
     \let\@BTswitch\@BTnormal
  \fi\fi
  \global\@thisrulewidth=#1\relax
  \ifnum\@thisruleclass=\tw@\vskip\@aboverulesep\else
  \ifnum\@lastruleclass=\z@\vskip\@aboverulesep\else
  \ifnum\@lastruleclass=\@ne\vskip\doublerulesep\fi\fi\fi
  \@BTswitch}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \toprule
    col1 & col2 & col3 \\
    \midrule
    row 2: & more and moooooooooooore & test \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\begin{xltabular}{0.7\linewidth}{cXc}
    \toprule
    col1 & col2 & col3 \\
    \midrule
    row 2: & more and moooooooooooore & test \\
    \bottomrule
\end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd simply replace `\ifx\xltabular\undefined` with `\ifcsname xltabular\endcsname`

Comment: @egreg that won't solve the bug. As soon as `\xltabular` has a hash-table entry, `booktabs` does no longer try to detect whether it is in a `longtable`-like environment or an ordinary `tabular` and just assumes it's always in a `longtable`-like environment. The test should never look whether `\xltabular` exists or not, but just on the meaning of `\hline`.