# The \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule do not extend past the first column when also using `xltabular`

Tags: tables, booktabs, xltabular

I am making a correlation matrix with `booktabs`. However, the `toprule` and similar commands do not extend past the first column when also using `\usepackage{xltabular}`. I tried to remove the `xltabular` package and this does indeed fix the problem but I cannot realistically forego this package in my project. How do I fix this?

PS: I am using Overleaf, so there is no issue with packages being not up-to-date in Miktex.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xltabular}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
        \centering
        \caption{Correlation matrix}
        \label{tab:mwe_table}
        \begin{tabular}{lrrrrrrr}
            \toprule
                & A     & B        & C                & D            & E        & F            & G \\ 
            \midrule
            A   &          & 0.14     & 0.07             & 0.15         & -0.23    & 0.36         & 0.20 \\ 
            B   & 0.14     &          & 0.07             & 0.71         & -0.45 & 0.69         & -0.09 \\ 
            C   & 0.07     & 0.07     &                  & 0.11         & 0.19     & 0.02         & -0.09 \\ 
            D   & 0.15  & 0.71     & 0.11             &              & -0.02 & 0.64         & 0.18  \\ 
            E   & -0.23 & -0.45 & 0.19             & -0.02     &          & -0.40     & 0.13  \\ 
            F     & 0.36     & 0.69  & 0.02             & 0.64         & -0.40 &              & -0.02 \\ 
            G     & 0.20     & -0.09 & -0.09         & 0.18         & 0.13     & -0.02     &  \\ 
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Table with xltabular imported]

[image: Table without xltabular imported]

Comment: Welcome! From your code I get [this output (click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpoIC.png) which is not pretty, to be honest, but has the full rules.

Comment: Note that using Overleaf does not mean that a package is up to date. Your exam,ple works fine for me.

Comment: Since you mention "do not extend past the first column when also using \usepackage{xltabular}": Does that mean you get the correct output if you remove `\usepackage{xltabular}`?

Comment: Former versions of `booktabs` had a bug when used together with `xltabular`. This is a known issue and should be fixed in recent versions. See here for a quick fix which should work with older versions: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/522927/117050

Comment: The `booktabs` provided on overleaf is `2019/10/08 v1.6180339`, while the latest version is `2020/01/12 v1.61803398`. The release log of [`2020/01/12`](https://ctan.org/ctan-ann/id/mailman.3249.1579100757.2586.ctan-ann@ctan.org) says "Reverting booktabs back to v1.618033", hence fixed the bug. @Skillmon I confirmed the patching codes in your linked answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/522927/ works on overleaf.

Comment: Given @Skillmonlikestopanswers.xyz's answer it might be that you need to tell OverLeaf to use the TeXLive 2020 engine instead. Though I don't know if Overleaf provides TL2020 yet

Comment: @leandriis Indeed. As I mention in the post: I tried to remove the `xltabular` package and this does indeed fix the problem.

Comment: @Skillmonlikestopanswers.xyz Great, that indeed works! I see you reported the bug to the maintainer of `booktabs` in January. Was there a response yet?

Comment: @daleif The latest TeXLive that shows up is indeed 2019 so it is not supported yet.

Comment: @MikeWeltevrede yes, as already mentioned the bug is fixed in recent versions (it took about a week or so, iirc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following to the preamble after importing `booktabs` and `xltabular` fixes the issue:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@BTrule[#1]{%
  \ifx\longtable\undefined
    \let\@BTswitch\@BTnormal
  \else\ifx\hline\LT@hline
    \nobreak
    \let\@BTswitch\@BLTrule
  \else
     \let\@BTswitch\@BTnormal
  \fi\fi
  \global\@thisrulewidth=#1\relax
  \ifnum\@thisruleclass=\tw@\vskip\@aboverulesep\else
  \ifnum\@lastruleclass=\z@\vskip\@aboverulesep\else
  \ifnum\@lastruleclass=\@ne\vskip\doublerulesep\fi\fi\fi
  \@BTswitch}
\makeatother
```

Source: [xltabular breaking booktabs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/522920/xltabular-breaking-booktabs)