# Tabularx continuing over multiple pages

Tags: tabularx, ltablex, xltabular

I have a `tabularx` table (6x2) with figure+text in all of its cells except the head. I've been trying to continue/flow this table over to the next page using packages like `ltablex` and `xltabular`, but in vain. Is it due to the fact that figures in `tabularx` hinder the table continuation over to the next page? Can anyone please show me an implementation of text+figure in all cells of `tabularx` with continuous flow of the table to the next page, if you can implement using `ltablex`/`xltabular`? I'll be grateful.

Here's my original `tabularx` code -

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs,makecell}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} >{\centering\arraybackslash}X | >{\centering\arraybackslash}X @{}}


\toprule 
     {\bfseries{Column 1}} & {\bfseries{Column 2}}  \\ 
     \midrule 
     %\endhead


\small \noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth} %\noalign{\vskip }
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Row 2 Column 1} 
   \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*]
   \item Something something something something. \par 
        \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth} \noindent
            \centering \noindent
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Illustrative.png}
            \captionof{figure}{Figure in enumeration in tabularx}
        \end{minipage}
   \item Something something something something.
   \item Something something something something.
   \end{enumerate}
%\noalign{\vskip }
\end{minipage} 

& \small \noindent     
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth} %\noalign{\vskip }
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Row 2 Column 2} 
   \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*]
   \item Something something something something. \par 
        \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth} \noindent
            \centering \noindent
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Illustrative.png}
            \captionof{figure}{Figure in enumeration in tabularx}
        \end{minipage}
   \item Something something something something.
   \item Something something something something.
   \end{enumerate}
%\noalign{\vskip }
\end{minipage}

  \\ \cmidrule(lr){1-2}


\small \noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth} %\noalign{\vskip }
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Row 3 Column 1} 
   \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*]
   \item Something something something something. \par 
        \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth} \noindent
            \centering \noindent
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Illustrative.png}
            \captionof{figure}{Figure in enumeration in tabularx}
        \end{minipage}
   \item Something something something something.
   \item Something something something something.
   \end{enumerate}
%\noalign{\vskip }
\end{minipage} 

& \small \noindent     
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth} %\noalign{\vskip }
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Row 3 Column 2} 
   \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*]
   \item Something something something something. \par 
        \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth} \noindent
            \centering \noindent
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Illustrative.png}
            \captionof{figure}{Figure in enumeration in tabularx}
        \end{minipage}
   \item Something something something something.
   \item Something something something something.
   \end{enumerate}
%\noalign{\vskip }
\end{minipage}

  \\ \cmidrule(lr){1-2}


\small \noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth} %\noalign{\vskip }
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Row 4 Column 1} 
   \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*]
   \item Something something something something. \par 
        \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth} \noindent
            \centering \noindent
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Illustrative.png}
            \captionof{figure}{Figure in enumeration in tabularx}
        \end{minipage}
   \item Something something something something.
   \item Something something something something.
   \end{enumerate}
%\noalign{\vskip }
\end{minipage} 

& \small \noindent     
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth} %\noalign{\vskip }
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Row 4 Column 2} 
   \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*]
   \item Something something something something. \par 
        \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth} \noindent
            \centering \noindent
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Illustrative.png}
            \captionof{figure}{Figure in enumeration in tabularx}
        \end{minipage}
   \item Something something something something.
   \item Something something something something.
   \end{enumerate}
%\noalign{\vskip }
\end{minipage}

  \\ \cmidrule(lr){1-2}


\small \noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth} %\noalign{\vskip }
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Row 5 Column 1} 
   \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*]
   \item Something something something something. \par 
        \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth} \noindent
            \centering \noindent
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Illustrative.png}
            \captionof{figure}{Figure in enumeration in tabularx}
        \end{minipage}
   \item Something something something something.
   \item Something something something something.
   \end{enumerate}
%\noalign{\vskip }
\end{minipage} 

& \small \noindent     
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth} %\noalign{\vskip }
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Row 5 Column 2} 
   \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*]
   \item Something something something something. \par 
        \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth} \noindent
            \centering \noindent
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Illustrative.png}
            \captionof{figure}{Figure in enumeration in tabularx}
        \end{minipage}
   \item Something something something something.
   \item Something something something something.
   \end{enumerate}
%\noalign{\vskip }
\end{minipage}

  \\ \cmidrule(lr){1-2}


\small \noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth} %\noalign{\vskip }
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Row 6 Column 1} 
   \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*]
   \item Something something something something. \par 
        \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth} \noindent
            \centering \noindent
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Illustrative.png}
            \captionof{figure}{Figure in enumeration in tabularx}
        \end{minipage}
   \item Something something something something.
   \item Something something something something.
   \end{enumerate}
%\noalign{\vskip }
\end{minipage} 

& \small \noindent     
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth} %\noalign{\vskip }
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Row 6 Column 2} 
   \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*]
   \item Something something something something. \par 
        \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth} \noindent
            \centering \noindent
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Illustrative.png}
            \captionof{figure}{Figure in enumeration in tabularx}
        \end{minipage}
   \item Something something something something.
   \item Something something something something.
   \end{enumerate}
%\noalign{\vskip }
\end{minipage}

  \\ \bottomrule 


%\label{tab:1} 
%    \caption{Something tabularx trying to flow to the next page.}

\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

And here's the output -

[image]

Comment: Welcome to  TeX SX! Which document class are you using?

Comment: @Bernard It's a custom made template that I imported from elsewhere. It's document class seems to be declared as `\usepackage[margin=0.8in]{geometry}`.

Comment: No, that's a  package for the layout The \documentclass,  normally, is the first line of code.

Comment: @Bernard. I see. Here's what I found then - `\documentclass[12pt]{article}`

Comment: I don't understand how that code is supposed to work. You cannot use `\noalign` inside a minipage. I wouldn't know what `\noalign{\vskip }` is supposed to mean, because `\vskip` should be followed by a length (or more accurately, a glue).
And you cannot use `\multicolumn` inside a minipage.
So how did you create that page?

Comment: @PietervanOostrum 1. You can run the code for yourself, works just fine with `\multicolumn` in minipage. 2. With or without `\noalign{\vskip }`, there isn’t much a difference, tbh I just added it to give a little indent. 3. Each minipage is in it's own cell, so `\linewidth` corresponds to the X width assigned by `tabularx`.

Comment: The code doesn't run for me. It gives a lot of errors. And you are right about the \linewidth, sorry about that. I deleted that comment.

Comment: @PietervanOostrum Alright then, can you maybe try just removing `\multicolumn` and `\noalign{\vskip }` parts of the code. I'm compiling in overleaf, and I'm getting the exact output that I showed without any errors, just few warnings. And I'm positive that the minipage part with `\linewidth` should work.

Comment: See for example:
                    
./ltabularxtest.tex:200: Misplaced \noalign.
<inserted text> ...page}[t]{\linewidth } \noalign 
                                                  {\vskip } \multicolumn {1}...l.200 \end{tabularx}
                    
This error is caused by the `\noalign{\vskip }`. The `\multicolumn` gives similar errors.

Comment: Nest error is about `\caption` and `\endhead`, which can't be used with `tabularx`.

Comment: @PietervanOostrum Yes, you’re right about `\caption` and `\endhead`. After removing them, can you maybe find a way to extend this table to the next page? I've tried both `ltablex` and `xltabular`, but they both don’t seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT 1: I found a solution for `\captionof`, see the code immediately after `\begin{document}`.**

I have cleaned up the code and used `ltablex`. That seems to work. (`xltabular` should probably also work, but it is incompatible with `booktabs`.) **EDIT 2:** I tried it with a cleaned up code, and it worked with `xltabular` and `booktabs`. Just replace `\usepackage{ltabularx}` with `\usepackage{xltabular}`, and the `tabularx` environment with `xltabular`.

There is only one thing: you cannot use `\captionof` inside the `minipage`, as it calls `\caption` and that is redefined by these packages in such a way that it must be used directly in the tabular, not inside anything else. So you must find a different solution for this.

To make the code simpler I have put the `minipage` in a macro. In real life you wouldn't do that, but in this way the code is shorter and easier to understand.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[margin=0.8in]{geometry}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}

\newcommand\onecell{
\small \noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
    \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*]
    \item Something something something something. \par 
         \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth} \noindent
             \centering \noindent
             \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
             \captionof{figure}{Figure in enumeration in tabularx}
         \end{minipage}
    \item Something something something something.
    \item Something something something something.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{minipage} 
}

\begin{document}
% This code must be after \begin{document}, not in the preamble
\newcommand\origcaption{}
\newcommand\origcaptionof{}
\let\origcaption\caption
\let\origcaptionof\captionof
\renewcommand{\captionof}{\let\caption\origcaption\origcaptionof}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} >{\centering\arraybackslash}X | >{\centering\arraybackslash}X @{}}

  \toprule 
     {\bfseries{Column 1}} & {\bfseries{Column 2}}  \\ 
     \midrule 
     \endhead

 \onecell
& 
 \onecell
  \\ \cmidrule(lr){1-2}

 \onecell
&
 \onecell
  \\ \cmidrule(lr){1-2}
 \onecell
&
 \onecell
  \\ \cmidrule(lr){1-2}
 \onecell
&
 \onecell
  \\ \cmidrule(lr){1-2}

 \onecell
&
 \onecell
  \\ \bottomrule 

    \caption{Something tabularx trying to flow to the next page.\label{tab:1}}

\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity: How do you come to the conclusion that `xltabular` is incompatible with `booktabs`?

Comment: @leandriis I got errors with `xltabular` and `booktabs` together, and there are other posts that describe this. For example https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/522920/113546
The solution given there, didn't work for me.

Comment: I tried it again with a cleaned up code, and now it worked with xltabular and booktabs.

Comment: @PietervanOostrum Thank you! Your solution for `\captionof` in minipage works like a charm.